# Any suggestions for dmenu in linux?

Tags: documentation

I downloaded linux and dmenu a while ago, and i would like to get deeper into dmenu. Does anyone know detailed instructions? I don't kinda understand how it works and i don't know how to run my own scripts in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It reads arbitrary text from stdin, and creates a menu with one item for each line.
The user can then select an item, through the arrow keys or typing a part of the name, and the line is printed to stdout.
`dmenu_run` is a wrapper that ships with the dmenu distribution that allows its use as an application launcher.
You might want to take a look at [the Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/dmenu) for some examples.

To change the font when using it:

```
$ dmenu_run -fn 'Droid Sans Mono-9'
```

As an application launcher, have it display a prompt, type to search, with customised font, background/foreground colors:

```
dmenu_run -nf '#BBBBBB' -nb '#222222' -sb '#251A10' -sf '#EEEEEE' -fn 'monospace-10' -p 'dmenu prompt >'
```

You can also consult the manual page [online](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dmenu) or from your linux distribution:

```
man dmenu
```